# Variables Access, get and post

Tags: python, google-app-engine, variables

how to get to these variables.
This is probably quite easy, but I do not think today.

```
class Contact(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        self.a = random.randint(1,4)
        self.b = random.randint(0,4)

        template_values = {
            'a': self.a,
            'b': self.b
        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'contact.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write(self.a)
        self.response.out.write(self.b)
```

Trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 702, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "D:\My Dropbox\project\main.py", line 133, in post
    self.response.out.write(self.a)
AttributeError: 'Contact' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: Where does the error happen? In `post`? What is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: yes in post, simple math captcha

Comment: we like to see full tracebacks.

Comment: I think this is because when i call post it is make new object. And how to deal with it

Answer (score 4):

Each request creates a new handler instance. For example, you can add this constructor to your handler:

```
class AppHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug('handler "%s" created' % self)
        super(AppHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    <...>
```

And make two requests, then in your logs you can see something like that:

```
DEBUG    2011-07-10 13:36:17,009 app.py:19] handler "<__main__.AppHandler object at 0x98dad8c>" created
<...>
DEBUG    2011-07-10 13:36:52,563 app.py:19] handler "<__main__.AppHandler object at 0x98de14c>" created
```

If you want to get some data between requests you can try to using some kind of sessions implementation. For example this: https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions.